# Does $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2g^{\mu\nu}\mathbb1$ determine the hermiticity of the gamma matrices?

Tags: conventions, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

If I remember correctly, the derivation of the Dirac equation requires that $\gamma^0$ is Hermitian while $\gamma^i$ for $i=1,2,3$ is anti-Hermitian. This is clearly true for the standard Dirac matrices, but does it follow from the algebra
$$\{\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\}= 2 g^{\mu\nu} \mathbb 1,\tag{1}$$
or do we need to impose it separately? By setting $\mu=\nu$ we find that
$$(\gamma^0)^2 = \mathbb 1, \quad (\gamma^i)^2 = -\mathbb 1,\tag{2}$$
and hence that
$$\det(\gamma^\mu) = \pm 1.\tag{3}$$
This is certainly consistent with the hermiticity relations, but I have not been able to prove that
$$(\gamma^0)^\dagger = \gamma^0, \quad (\gamma^i)^\dagger = -\gamma^i\tag{4}$$
from (1) alone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think so.  If $\gamma^\mu$ is a set  of gamma matrices obeying the clifford algebra, then so is $S^{-1}\gamma^\mu S$ for any invertible $S$. But unless $S$ is unitary,   $\gamma^\mu$  being hermitian does not imply  that  $S^{-1}\gamma^\mu S$ hermitian.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Do you happen to know if the hermiticity relations (4) are necessary for the Dirac equation (to make sense), or is it sufficient that the gamma matrices satisfy the Clifford algebra (1)?

Comment: I think the hermiticity is just convenenient for a simple life. One can always redefine the $\psi$'s by $\psi\to S\psi$, but this will affect other inner products.

Comment: Hmm, I just found something that seems to contradict your answer, but unfortunately the source gives no proof. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) says *"A fundamental theorem states that if two distinct sets of matrices are given that both satisfy the Clifford relations, then they are connected to each other by a similarity transformation: $\gamma'^\mu=S^{-1}\gamma^\mu S$. If in addition the matrices are all unitary, as are the Dirac set, then S itself is unitary"*. If this is true then argument in your answer does not work as is.

Comment: The statement in italics in your comment is correct but does not contradict what I said:  If the $\gamma^\mu$ are unitary and $S$ is unitary, then ${\gamma'}^\mu$ are unitary. If $S$ is *not* unitary then ${\gamma'}^\mu$ *need not* be unitary.  So Clifford does not imply any form of unitarity.  Dirac chose his set to be (anti) unitary, but there are other choices.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread it. Thank you!